# Python binding to ImageMagick

Tags: python, binding, imagemagick, wand

I am looking for a good Python binding to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), but there seem a lot of bindings already. I am not sure that which of these is the right tool for my job. Can you guys recommend me one?

Here is the list of my requirements and preferences (in order of importance):

1. Must be available on PyPI (to simplify our deployment)
2. Prefer `ctypes` over C API extension — we will go PyPy soon
3. Pythonic API design and naming conventions
4. Good documentation (especially API references)

Comment: the offical python bindings are at http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/ the file `PythonMagick-0.9.7.tar.gz` was updated at 11-Aug-2011

Comment: @DanD. No, it is not available on PyPI and it’s my least requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I access ImageMagick API with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895278/can-i-access-imagemagick-api-with-python)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<del>I found the package myself: [magickwand](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/magickwand) is a `ctypes`-based ImageMagick binding for Python. Yet it has no documentation at all, it still satisfies most of my requirements.</del>

Plus: I finally started my own project: [Wand](http://wand-py.org/).