# Manipulating Google Cardboard photo in Python

Tags: python, google-cardboard, xmp

I would like to manipulate a Google Cardboard photo under Windows 10 with a Python script. I am using PIL. Reading the image data and writing the manipulated image back works fine, but then I lose the XMP metadata, without which Google Cardboard (for good reason) won't accept the image.

I tried using python-xmp-toolkit for reading and writing the XMP data, but the first thing that I get is an error about Exempi missing. I found suggestions saying to compile it from source. This sounds like a rabbit hole I don't want to enter.

Does anyone know a good route for me to take here?

Comment: I found https://dusan-pacal.medium.com/how-i-managed-to-resize-an-image-and-keep-all-the-exif-and-xmp-metadata-using-python-fa68172ee479 , which looked promising, and it seems to copy a lot of metadata, but Google Cardboard is still not happy with the result.

Comment: "I get is an error about Exempi missing" That could be a question on its own.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895278/can-i-access-imagemagick-api-with-python